# PowerShell - Extract data from XML, then find in directory

Tags: xml, powershell

I hope I can get some much needed advice for a piece of work I have given up on a few occasions. *Note I had no input to how the current design is.

**Current process**

We get applications through our website, once the application has been complete a DIRECTORY is created with a unique ID as the name – Then a SUBDIRECTORY with another Unique ID is created. These reside within a PARENT folder called ‘Applications’

Within this SUBDIRECTORY there is a list of files;

- Application_Form.pdf (Only 1 exists)
- Proof_of_address.jpg (applicant can upload 1 – 10 images)
- Passport_Photo.jpg (applicant can upload 1 – 10 images)
- Photo.jpg (applicant can upload 1 – 10 images)
- Application.xml (Only 1 exists)

[image: Directory]

We currently have a task schedule triggers a .bat script every 5 minutes which moves every folder in the ‘Applications’ directory to an internal server.

The problem we often experience is the script doesn’t care what files are in those directories so if an applicant is part way through uploading documents, not all documents are pulled across.

**The Solution**

Create a PowerShell script that;

1. Extracts the filenames from applications.xml
2. Does an ‘if exists’ with those filenames.
3. If all files exist in directory then move the top level directory to the internal server.
4. If not exist, skip and go to next directory.

The Applications.xml captures all the filenames and can be treated as ‘gospel’.

**XML Example**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DOCUMENTS>
  <DOCUMENT>
    <DOCTYPE>APPLIC</DOCTYPE>
    <FILENAME>Proof1 Bank Statement.jpg</FILENAME>
    <IMAGES>
      <IMAGE SOURCE="Proof1_721ee515-8a29-4898-acb1-696acfa288a1.jpg"></IMAGE>
    </IMAGES>
  </DOCUMENT>
  <DOCUMENT>
    <DOCTYPE>APPLIC</DOCTYPE>
    <FILENAME>Passport1.jpg</FILENAME>
    <IMAGES>
      <IMAGE SOURCE="Passport1_721ee515-8a29-4898-acb1-696acfa288a1.jpg"></IMAGE>
    </IMAGES>
  </DOCUMENT>
  <DOCUMENT>
    <DOCTYPE>PHOTO</DOCTYPE>
    <FILENAME>Photo.jpg</FILENAME>
    <IMAGES>
      <IMAGE SOURCE="Photo1_721ee515-8a29-4898-acb1-696acfa288a1.jpg"></IMAGE>
    </IMAGES>
  </DOCUMENT>
  <DOCUMENT>
    <DOCTYPE>APPLIC</DOCTYPE>
    <FILENAME>Application_Form_721ee515-8a29-4898-acb1-696acfa288a1.pdf</FILENAME>
    <IMAGES>
      <IMAGE SOURCE="Application_Form_721ee515-8a29-4898-acb1-696acfa288a1.pdf"></IMAGE>
    </IMAGES>
  </DOCUMENT>
</DOCUMENTS>
```

**This is my script so far:**

```
$Path = "C:\Temp\Scripts\Transfer\Applications\*\*\*.xml"
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter *xml | ForEach-Object {


$XPath = "//IMAGE"
Select-Xml -Path $Path -XPath $Xpath | Select-Object -ExpandProperty node

} 

}
```

This outputs as;

```
SOURCE                                                                                                                                                                   
------                                                                                                                                                                   
Proof1_721ee515-8a29-4898-acb1-696acfa288a1.jpg                                                                                                                          
Passport1_721ee515-8a29-4898-acb1-696acfa288a1.jpg                                                                                                                      
Photo1_721ee515-8a29-4898-acb1-696acfa288a1.jpg                                                                                                                          
Application_Form_721ee515-8a29-4898-acb1-696acfa288a1.pdf
```

With this in mind I am stuck at step one, use PowerShell to capture the filenames in applications.xml. I have managed to get the above result, but only in bulk form. How could I split this list into individual results so I can then do a an ‘if exists’ function to check the directory for the above files and if all of the above exist, copy the top level directory within Applications to the internal server?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You can output each 'source' attribute as a separate string by changing `Select-Xml -Path $Path -XPath $Xpath | Select-Object -ExpandProperty node` to `(Select-Xml -Path $_.Fullname -XPath $Xpath).Node.Source`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it correctly. Just need to add one more step to get the output of `Select-Xml` into a varibale and loop through it like this.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter *xml | ForEach-Object {

$dirPath = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($_.FullName)
Write-Host $_.FullName
Write-Host $dirPath

$XPath = "//IMAGE"
$files = Select-Xml -Path $_.FullName -XPath $Xpath | Select-Object -ExpandProperty node
Foreach($file in $files)
{
#Write-Host $file.SOURCE
  if((Test-Path "$dirPath\$($file.SOURCE)")){
    Write-Host "File Exist $dirPath\$($file.SOURCE)";
  }
  else{
        Write-Host "File doesn't Exist $dirPath\$($file.SOURCE)";
  }
} 

}
```

Comment: Thank you for that, if the Base file path is wild-carded how can I define that in <Your-Base-Path>?

Comment: use `$_.FullName` to get the selected xml file and `[System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($_.FullName)` to get the directory path.